# Java: PubsubMessage Subscriber receives message with no data or attribute

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to receive message to a topic and receive the message in the subscriber. But in the subscriber I don't receive any message, only an empty `PubsubMessage`.

**Subscriber**

```
package com.dsam.assignment02.functions;

import com.google.cloud.functions.BackgroundFunction;
import com.google.cloud.functions.Context;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class OrderBillPdfGeneratorFunction implements BackgroundFunction<PubsubMessage> {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(OrderBillPdfGeneratorFunction.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void accept(PubsubMessage payload, Context context) throws Exception {
        String s = payload.getData().isEmpty() ? "No data" : new String(
            Base64.getDecoder().decode(payload.getData().toByteArray()),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8
        );
        String t = String.valueOf(payload.getAttributesCount());
        logger.log(Level.INFO, String.format("Data: %s\nAttribute Count: %s", s, t));
    }
}
```

**Log Output**

```
Data: No data
Attribute Count: 0
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

**Update**

I published message from cloud console pub/sub topic, but still didn't receive any data, which rules out the possiblity of issue being related to the publisher code.

Comment: Any help anyone?

Comment: Can you share your whole JAVA file? Especially to see which import that you perform

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I've updated the code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I fugured out the problem. I had to define my own class for function parameter instead of using `com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage`.

Defined below `PubSubMessage` class and used as `public class OrderBillPdfGeneratorFunction implements BackgroundFunction<PubSubMessage>`

```
public static class PubSubMessage {
    public String data;
    public Map<String, String> attributes;
    public String messageId;
    public String publishTime;
}
```

This solved the issue.

**EDIT**

Here's the full working code.

```
package com.dsam.assignment02.functions;

import com.google.cloud.functions.BackgroundFunction;
import com.google.cloud.functions.Context;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class OrderBillPdfGeneratorFunction implements BackgroundFunction<PubSubMessage> {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(OrderBillPdfGeneratorFunction.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void accept(PubSubMessage payload, Context context) throws Exception {
        String s = payload.getData().isEmpty() ? "No data" : new String(
            Base64.getDecoder().decode(payload.getData().toByteArray()),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8
        );
        String t = String.valueOf(payload.getAttributesCount());
        logger.log(Level.INFO, String.format("Data: %s\nAttribute Count: %s", s, t));
    }

    public static class PubSubMessage {
        public String data;
        public Map<String, String> attributes;
        public String messageId;
        public String publishTime;
    }
}
```